# Rebase local branch with upstream branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase, branching-and-merging

Chain of events after forking a repo:

1. Created a branch
2. Made some changes
3. Submitted PR of my branch to upstream master
4. Repo owner creates a branch on his repository and merges my PR along with some other changes.

I still have work to do on the PR, but now I have to rebase my branch on the branch that the repo owner created to test some things before my branch can be merged with his master.

How can I rebase the branch in my local repo with the branch created in the remote? I basically want one of my branches to be the same as one of the branches in the upstream repo (not master).

Apologies in advance for the potentially poor use of terminology.

Comment: Why can't you just keep working on your original branch, then have the Repo owner re-merge into his remote branch when you update your PR?

Comment: I think it was because in the repo owner's branch the testing suite was updated so that I can run it with a different version of the programming language, along with some other recent changes. So I'll need those in my branch before I'm able to test and make additional changes based off of those tests.

Comment: Other alternative I think would be to open a new PR working off of the branch that the repo owner created but it would be cleaner to keeping working within the same PR.

Comment: Given that the owner has already merged, you're probably not going to be able to get a totally "clean" option.  Your best bet might be to pull the newly created branch from the remote and merge it __into__ your original PR branch.  That is, unless there's **another** remote branch that has just the remote's changes in place (updated test suite, etc.), prior to his merging your PR; if you could pull **that** branch, then your rebase would be "clean".

Comment: Okay so how would I go about the former (unfortunately the latter is not feasible but I could see that being a lot cleaner)? Maybe a `git fetch upstream` then `git merge remote-branch` from the PR branch?

Comment: Yes, essentially.  But, before you do, you should probably check w/ repo owner that he's OK with re-merging your updated PR once you finish your updates (I don't foresee any issues, since he merged instead of rebased your PR in the first place, but owners can sometimes be finicky).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I rebase the branch in my local repo with the branch created in the remote? I basically want one of my branches to be the same as one of the branches in the upstream repo (not master).

The usual way:

```
git rebase upstream/the_branch
```

This will change the history of your branch that you used in the PR.
But that's fine. Since your PR is not accepted yet, and as you said it needs more work, it's ok to rewrite its underlying branch,
when you're done, with:

```
git push -f origin yourbranch_for_pr
```

As a side note,
after this, in the PR you will see all your changes made before the rebase, and after, but also the other changes made by the repo owner if those changes were not yet merged into `master`. It will be ideal if the repo owner merges his changes into `master` first, and then your PR will contain only your work, which will be more clear.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sync your branch with upstream and you have really no commits locally that you want to keep, the easier is to reset:

```
git reset --hard upstream/the_branch
```

You could also specify directly a sha1.